# Xcode 3.2.4 code sense does not work with UIPopoverController

Tags: xcode, autocomplete, uipopovercontroller

Code sense is not giving me any options for `UIPopoverController` in my universal app. No `initWithContentViewController` for init options, no `popoverContentSize` for the instance, etc...

Setting project format to Xcode 3.2-compatible and rebuilding the the Code Sense index did not help.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I find exactly the same question as yours.  And what I can find is only a work-around solution: build when selecting the target to "device" not "Simulator", then the code sense works. But if you shift back to "Simulator" and build again, it doesn't work.

I also hope someone could find a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Click "Get Info" at your project name located at left hand side. And select "General", "Base SDK for All Configurations" -> iOS Simulator 3.2, then "Rebuild Code Sense index"